# How do I get td value by comparing tr index value using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I get `td` value by comparing tr index value using jQuery

[image]

I tried like

```
var index = parseInt(tr.attr("index")); //this is giving index value
```

now based on index value want to check `prop = myid`

```
var id = $("tr:eq(0)").find("td[prop*='myid']").html();
```

could any one correct me var id expression

Comment: try `var id = $("tr[index=0]").find("td[prop=myid]").html();`

Comment: `index value is not fixed is changed every time`
and this expression gives index value ` var index = parseInt(tr.attr("index"));`

Comment: `var id = $("tr[index="+index+"]").find("td[prop=myid]").html();`

Comment: my bad i missed syntax '' :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the index value with the selector

```
var index = parseInt(tr.attr("index"));
var id = $("tr[index=" + index + "]").find("td[prop=myid]").html();
```